# Change the Timezone

Tags: code-golf, date

### Challenge

Given a time and a timezone as input, output the time in that timezone.

### Time

The time will be given in 24 hour format like so:

```
hh:mm
```

Where hh is the two digit hour and mm is the two digit minute. Note that the hour and the minute will always be padded with zeroes like so:

```
06:09
```

All the times given are at UTC+00:00.

*The hours in your output do not have to be padded wih zeroes but your time it must be in 24 hour format*

### Timezone

The timezone will be given in the following format:

```
UTC±hh:mm
```

Where ± is either going to be a + or a - and hh, is the two digit hour and mm is the two digit minute (again, these will be padded with zeroes).

To find the time in that timezone, you either add (if the symbol is +) or subtract (if the symbol is -) the time after the UTC± from the inputted time.

For example, if the input was `24:56` and `UTC-02:50`, you would subtract 2 hours and 50 minutes from 24:56:

```
24:56
02:50 -
-----
22:06
```

The output would be `22:06`.

### Examples

#### Chicago

```
Input:  08:50 and UTC-06:00
Output: 02:50
```

#### Kathmandu

```
Input:  09:42 and UTC+05:45
Output: 15:27
```

#### Samoa

```
Input:  06:42 and UTC+13:00
Output: 19:42
```

#### Hawaii

```
Input:  02:40 and UTC-10:00
Output: 16:40
```

Note that this has gone to the previous day.

#### Tokyo

```
Input:  17:25 and UTC+09:00
Output: 02:25
```

Note that this has gone to the following day.

### Rules

You must not use any built in date functions or libraries.

Assume all input will be valid times and time offsets.

The timezone will be in the range `UTC-24:00` to `UTC+24:00` inclusive.

In the case of *half past midnight*, the correct representation should be `00:30`, ***not*** `24:30`.

### Winning

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: What about TimeSpan/Duration methods/classes? I assume those are also excluded

Comment: Also will input values always be valid times? Ie `26:02` and `08:74` would not appear? Same for the UTC offsets?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 1) Yes, all of those excluded. 2) Assume all input is valid

Comment: Do we have to pad the output with zeroes? (eg. Can the last test case output `2:25`)

Comment: @Loovjo No, the output does no have to be padded

Comment: 24:54 or 00:54? Also is UTC+14:00 a valid input?

Comment: Shouldn't the second test case be `15:27`?

Comment: @betseg `00:24` and I've added a range of acceptable time offsets

Comment: Please add a test case for MART and/or NST.

Comment: @Neil May I ask why? Surely the same principle is demonstrated by the Kathmandu time

Comment: If the output doesn't need to be padded would a time like `1:5` be valid instead of `1:05`? I'd think only the hours shouldn't be padded. Also your example with `24:56` should that not be `00:56` since you've stated a range up to `24:00` and express similar in your half past midnight scenario?

Comment: Is the time guaranteed to be the first input, or can the inputs be in either order?

Comment: @BetaDecay In case an answer subtracts 3 hours but then and adds 30 minutes by mistake.

Comment: @Tortoise Post it as a non-competing entrant, if you like :) Just remember to put `non-competing` in the header

Comment: Could the input be a single string such as `"17:25 UTC+09:00"`?

Comment: @Arnauld Your input may be taken in anyway you wish, as long is follows the format given in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog APL)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 45 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

#### Expression

Takes two strings as right argument.

```apl
24 60⊤∘⍎∘⍕('+-'∩⍕),'/',(0 60⊥2⊃':'⎕VFI ¯5∘↑)¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@///f8ijtglGJgpmBo@6ljzqmPGotw9MTtVQ19ZVf9SxEsjU1FHXV9fRMAArWmr0qKtZ3Ur9Ud/UMDdPhUPrTUHq2yZqHlrBFaKgbmBhZWqgrqAeGuKsa2BmZQBkP@qdq@CckZmcmJ4PVmFpZWIEUaFtYGplYgpR4Z1YkpGbmJdSClZjhlBjaAw3JTgxNz8RLG9kZQKzxdAALu@RWJ6YmQlSYGhuZWQKs8QSriAkP7syHwA)

#### Explanation

`24 60⊤` the number-to-base-*a*<sub>24</sub>*b*<sub>60</sub> conversion

`∘` of

`⍎` the evaluation

`∘` of

`⍕` the formatted (i.e. flattened with separating spaces)

`('+-'∩⍕)` intersection of "+-" and the formatted input (this extracts the plus or minus)

`,` followed by

`(`...`)¨` the following for each of the inputs (the time and the offset)

`0 60⊥` the *a*<sub>∞</sub>*b*<sub>60</sub>-to-number conversion of

`2⊃` the second element of

`':'⎕VFI`  the, using colon as field separator, **V**erified and **F**ixed **I**nput of

`¯5∘↑` the last five characters ("hh:mm")

#### Step-by-step on "17:25" and "UTC+09:00"

The left-side expression on the right side data, gives the data of the next line.

```
                       '17:25' 'UTC+09:00'
                      /     /   \         \
(...)¨ applies the function train to both inputs
                    /     /       \         \
¯5∘↑               '17:25'         'UTC+09:00'
':'⎕VFI            '17:25'         '09:00' 
2⊃            (1 1)(17 25)         (1 1)(9 0)
0 60⊥                17 25         9 0
                      1045         540
                       \  \       / /
This is where ¨ stops, and execution continues on the resulting list
                         \  \   / /
'/',                      1045 540
('+-'∩⍕),             '/' 1045 540
⍕                 '+' '/' 1045 540
⍎                   '+ / 1045 540'
24 60⊤                        1585
                              2 25
```

Answer (score 3):

## C, 109 bytes

```
a,b,c;f(char*t,char*z){for(c=0;z[3];t=z+=3)sscanf(t,"%d:%d",&a,&b),c+=b+a*60;printf("%d:%02d",c/60%24,c%60);}
```

Invoke as follows:

```
int main() { f("17:25", "UTC+09:00"); }
```

Comment: How does this work for negative time offsets e.g. `UTC-03:30`?

Comment: Oops, I forgot about those, but thankfully, it’s an easy fix.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 101 bytes

```
(t,z,g=s=>+(s[3]+s[7]+s[8])+s.slice(3,6)*60,m=g('UTC+'+t)+g(z)+1440)=>(m/60%24|0)+':'+(m/10%6|0)+m%10
```

Would be 121 bytes if I padded the hours.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 129 bytes

```
def T(t,a):f=[int.__add__,int.__sub__]["-"in a];m=f(int(t[3:5]),int(a[7:9]));print`f(int(t[0:2])+m/60,int(a[4:6]))%24`+":"+`m%60`
```

Call as `T("02:45", "UTC-05:33")`

Comment: Missing leading zeros in formatted output. Should say Python 2 in heading. Could reduce to a one line function with `;`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan [You don't need padding zeroes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92916/change-the-timezone/92920?noredirect=1#comment226188_92916),

Comment: Ah, cool, missed that bit! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 84 bytes

```python
def f(t,z):i=int;r=60*(i(t[:2])+i(z[3:6]))+i(t[3:])+i(z[3]+z[7:]);print r/60%24,r%60
```

All test cases are at [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/vsxuOa)

Output format is space separated, with no leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 201 bytes

```
String T(String t,String z){return(24+Integer.valueOf(t.substring(0,2))+Integer.valueOf((String)z.subSequence(3,6)))%24+":"+(60+Integer.valueOf(t.substring(3,5))+Integer.valueOf(z.substring(7,9)))%60;}
```

Called as 
    T("12:00", "UTC+02:40")

Unglolfed for the logic,

```
String T(String t, String z) { 
    int i = (24 + Integer.valueOf(t.substring(0, 2)) + Integer.valueOf((String) z.subSequence(3, 6))) % 24;
    int j = (60 + Integer.valueOf(t.substring(3, 5)) + Integer.valueOf(z.substring(7, 9))) % 60;
    return i + ":" + j;
}
```

Any help to get it under 200 would be appreciated!

Comment: This is flawed. Doesn't fulfil the 2nd test (where the hour is incremented). Also, to reduce, why do you use subSequence instead of substring? To golf more, declare `Integer i=1;` and replace all other `Integer` by `i`, so you have `i.valueOf` instead of `Integer.valueOf`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire huh? Could you elaborate on the second test please!

Comment: For the Kathmandu test case, you output `14:27` instead of `15:27`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire ah good point

Comment: Or even `java.util.function.Function v=Integer::valueOf`. Not sure if that would actually save much.

Comment: You could also do something tricky like `interface V{int a(String s);}` then in your function `V v=Integer::valurOf`, then each valueOf would be reduced to `v.a`. Not sure if worth it over the `Integer i=1` approach

Comment: You can replace the four `Integer.valueOf(...)` to `new Long(...)` (PS / FYI: Both `Integer.decode(...)` and `new Integer(...)` are also shorter than `Integer.valueOf(...)`, and there is also a fourth option to parse String to an integer which is longer: `Integer.parseInt(...)`.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `Integer.decode(String)` won't work with values like `09`. `new Integer(String)` is longer if Womba fixes his issues mentioned in comment 1.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>93</s> 92 bytes

```
t=>((t=eval(t.replace(/.*?(.)?(..):(..)/g,'$1($2*60+$3)+720')))/60%24|0)+':'+(t/10%6|0)+t%10
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =
t=>((t=eval(t.replace(/.*?(.)?(..):(..)/g,'$1($2*60+$3)+720')))/60%24|0)+':'+(t/10%6|0)+t%10

console.log(f("08:50 UTC-06:00")); //  2:50
console.log(f("09:42 UTC+05:45")); // 15:27
console.log(f("06:42 UTC+13:00")); // 19:42
console.log(f("02:40 UTC-10:00")); // 16:40
console.log(f("17:25 UTC+09:00")); //  2:25
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 95 bytes

```
g=->s{"60*"+s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)*?+}
f=->t,z{r=eval(g[t]+z[3]+g[z]);print r/60%24,?:,r%60}
```

### Usage

```
f[gets,gets]
```

#### Inputs(example)

```
08:50
UTC-06:00
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# <strike>214</strike> <strike>205</strike> 183 Bytes

```
string f(char[]t,char[]u){int s=~(u[3]-45),z=48,m=(t[3]-z)*10+t[4]-z+((u[7]-z)*10+u[8]-z)*s,h=(t[0]-z)*10+t[1]-z+((u[4]-z)*10+u[5]-z)*s+m/60+(m>>8)+24;return$"{h%24}:{(m+60)%60:D2}";}
```

205 byte version

```
string f(string t,string u){Func<string,int>P=int.Parse;var T=t.Split(':');int s=u[3]<45?1:-1,m=P(T[1])+P(u.Substring(7))*s,h=P(T[0])+P($"{u[4]}"+u[5])*s+m/60+(m<0?-1:0)+24;return$"{h%24}:{(m+60)%60:D2}";}
```

Ungolfed

```
string f(char[] t, char[] u)
{
    int s = ~(u[3]-45),
        z = 48,
        m = (t[3] - z) * 10 + t[4] - z + ((u[7] - z) * 10 + u[8] - z) * s,
        h = (t[0] - z) * 10 + t[1] - z + ((u[4] - z) * 10 + u[5] - z) * s + m / 60 + (m>>8) + 24;
    return $"{h % 24}:{(m + 60) % 60:D2}";
}
```

Original 214:

```
string f(string t,string u){Func<string,int>P=int.Parse;var T=t.Split(':');int h=P(T[0]),m=P(T[1]),s=u[3]<45?1:-1;m+=P(u.Substring(7))*s;h+=P($"{u[4]}"+u[5])*s+m/60+(m<0?-1:0)+24;return$"{h%24:D2}:{(m+60)%60:D2}";}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java <del>156</del> <del>150</del> <del>149</del> <del>147</del> 142 bytes

```
t->z->{Integer H=100,T=H.valueOf(t.replace(":","")),Z=H.valueOf(z.replace(":","").substring(3)),c=(T/H+Z/H+24)*60+T%H+Z%H;return c/60%24+":"+c%60;}
```

### Test cases & ungolfed

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BiFunction<String,String,String> f = (t,z)->{
            Integer H = 100, // Hundred, used several times, shorter as variable
                    T = H.valueOf(t.replace(":","")), // as int (HHMM)
                    Z = H.valueOf(z.replaceAll("[UTC:]","")), // as int (-HHMM)
                    c = (T/H + Z/H + 24) * 60 + T%H + Z%H; // transform into minutes
            return c/60%24+":"+c%60;
        };

        test(f, "08:50", "UTC-06:00", "02:50");
        test(f, "09:42", "UTC+05:45", "15:27");
        test(f, "03:42", "UTC-05:45", "21:57");
        test(f, "06:42", "UTC+13:00", "19:42");
        test(f, "02:40", "UTC-10:00", "16:40");
        test(f, "17:25", "UTC+09:00", "02:25");
    }

    private static void test(BiFunction<String,String,String> f, String time, String zone, String expected) {
        // Padding is allowed. Make sure the padding is skipped for the test, then.
        String result = String.format("%2s:%2s", (Object[])f.apply(time, zone).split(":")).replace(" ","0");
        if (result.equals(expected)) {
            System.out.printf("%s + %s: OK%n", time, zone);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s + %s: Expected \"%s\", got \"%s\"%n", time, zone, expected, result);
        }

    }
}
```

### Shavings

- 150 -> 149: `a/H*60+b/H*60` -> `(a/H+b/H)*60`
- 149 -> 147: `(T/H+Z/H)*60+1440` -> `(T/H+Z/H+24)*60`.
- 147 -> 142: `z.replace(":","").substring(3)` -> `z.replaceAll("[UTC:]","")`

Answer (score 0):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 40 bytes

```
r{':/60b}:F~r3>(\F\~1440,=60b{s2Te[}%':*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#Lco/C8IwFATwvZ/CRSr@IS@vedFe0UXoKLS2k3URXAVxDMlXj6lxOfjd3fui3FUFdA36JvauhLL08GhDV51WUzsFbQxtj6l0Hx6eN78ssY73l1eRCGIX43DeEUOooEPKbAtKrmF49oYERorU/q2r384w@a9ptt6DJf/r5C8) (As a test suite.)

#### Explanation

```
r           e# Read first input (time).
{':/60b}:F  e# Define a function F, which splits a string around ':' and
            e# treats the two elements as base-60 digits.
~           e# Run that function on the first input.
r3>         e# Read the second input and discard the 'UTC'.
(           e# Pull off the +-.
\F          e# Apply F to the timezone offset.
\~          e# Execute the + or - on the two amounts of minutes.
1440,=      e# Modulo 1440 to fit everything into the 24-hour format.
60b         e# Obtain base 60 digits again.
{s2Te[}%    e# Convert each digit to a string and pad it to 2 decimal digits.
':*         e# Join them with a ':'.
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 100 bytes

```
:
59$*:,
+`(\d+):
$1,$1
\d+
$*
T`1`0`-.+
^
1440$*
+`10|\D

1{1440}

^(1{60})*(.*)
$#1:$.2
\b\d\b
0$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LcpBDoIwEAXQ/T@FiaMpLZCZ2qLMVhMvgLvGNIRbIGfHIm4m8/7/J/PMqyL2ZLWGyyZNrlKQ1CQoP8hiyJI5N63DGxICl8hl4U96ADJvyQK8jcwdL5U1ra1AR1FqPdKYpjSC6byuzBq7w2u4N@w1MvhW7u5OubjX4Dc7jhoiSvq3XH6917DvhTfLVX3c933xFw)

#### Explanation

```
:
59$*:,
```

Replaces each `:` with 59 of them and a comma as a separator.

```
+`(\d+):
$1,$1
```

Repeatedly duplicates the number in front of a `:`. So the first two stages multiply the hour-value by 60.

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert each number to unary.

```
T`1`0`-.+
```

If there's a minus sign in the input, then this transliteration stage turns all the `1`s after it into `0`s. We're basically using `0` as a unary `-1` digit here.

```
^
1440$*
```

Insert 1440 `1`s (i.e. a full day). This is to ensure that the time doesn't get negative.

```
+`10|\D
```

This repeatedly removes all non-digits (i.e. the space, the `UTC`, the `+` or `-`, as well as all the `,` we've inserted) and the `10` combination, thereby cancelling positive and negative digits. This basically subtracts the second number from the first if it's negative, or adds it otherwise.

```
1{1440}
```

Removes 1440 `1`s if possible (basically taking the result modulo 1440 to fit it into a single 24 hours).

```
^(1{60})*(.*)
$#1:$.2
```

Decompose the number into hours and minutes by matching as many chunks of 60 digits as possible (counting the chunks with `$#1`) followed by the remaining digits (whose length is counted with `$.2`).

```
\b\d\b
0$&
```

If there are any single digits in the result, prepend a zero.