# Time calculator

Tags: code-golf, date

This challenge is related to a project I did last year (in Ruby). To make it more fun I decided to do it in as few bytes as possible. I didn't know about code golf back then so now that I found out about it and found this community I was wondering if anybody can beat me :)

The program should return the current time if no input is given

```
ruby time.rb
12:24
```

Or if you enter a time as a parameter it should return the time it will be in so many hours/minutes (pretend the time is 12:24) (the parts in `[]` are optional):

```
ruby time.rb [+]2[:12]
14:36
```

Or if the input starts with a `-` then subtract that time:

```
ruby time.rb -2[:12]
10:12
```

Of course if you don't include the `:12` then it will only subtract the hours.

In Ruby I managed to get it at 144 bytes.

Of course you can do this in any language you like. However I would be happy to see if anybody can do any better in Ruby.

**Edit:**

Yes it is similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92916/change-the-timezone) challenge. However I think it is different in a couple of ways.

1. The program has to get the date and it is not provided by the user
2. The input has many different formats `01:00`, `1:00`, `1`, `+1`, `-1`, `1:23` etc.

I think these make it different enough but if you disagree then I will happily let go and allow it to be marked as duplicate.

**Rules:**

- You must support all input formats I showed.
- You are allowed to use any method to calculate the time (except for asking the user)
- The output format must be `HH:MM`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I judged too quickly. I have reverted my edits.

Comment: @LeakyNun No worries. I was just about to message for clarification. Being new to the community I thought I misunderstood something :)

Comment: Can we output the seconds too or should it be only hours:minutes ?

Comment: @Dada Only hours and minutes. The output has to be exactly like I showed in my examples.

Comment: @BetaDecay Please see my edit concerning the duplicate question.

Comment: Do we have to support all the input formats or only a subset of them? For example, Can I force input to need to have a `+` on the front or do I have to support with a `+` and without?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder  Well, my project required me to support all of them so I am going to say all.

Comment: `The output has to be exactly like I showed in my examples`: Do we need leading zeroes for the output `01:11`? Or can we use `1:11`?